# Evaluate $\int {dx\over \sqrt[6]{(x-7)^7(x-5)^5}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate :
>   $$
> \int {dx\over \sqrt[6]{(x-7)^7(x-5)^5}}
> $$

The most obvious idea would be setting:
$$
t^6 = (x-7)^7(x-5)^5
$$

But then the problem becomes too complicated, since finding $dx$ is not that simple. I believe there must be some smart substitution which I couldn't find.

I was then thinking of setting:
$$
t = x-7\\
dx = dt\\
\sqrt[6]{(x-7)^7(x-5)^5} = \sqrt[6]{t^7(t+2)^5}
$$
So that the integral becomes:
$$
\int {dt\over \sqrt[6]{t^7(t+2)^5}}
$$

Which again leads to complicated calculations. Could someone suggest a way to solve that integral?

Comment: You can use this site <https://www.integral-calculator.com/> which provides a step-by-step solution to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's do a more general case:
$$I(n)=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{(x-(n+1))^{n+1}(x-(n-1))^{n-1}}}\overset{x-n=t}=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt[n]{(t-1)^{n+1}(t+1)^{n-1}}}$$
$$=\int \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)\sqrt[n]{ \frac{t-1}{t+1}}}\overset{(t-1)/(t+1)=y}=\frac12\int \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{\sqrt[n]{y}}=-\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{y}}+C,\quad y=\frac{x-n-1}{x-n+1}$$

Comment: Whoa, that's neat, thank you!

Comment: It should be said that the domain of validity of such an integral is outside interval $[n-1,n+1]$.